# How to mock Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file, "UTF-8") in Roboelectric

Tags: android, robolectric

I am facing an issue to mock below mention line using Roboelectric or Powermockito

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir() + FILE_NAME);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file, "UTF-8")
```

it throws me the below exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: "data/data/Logs/Text.txt" (The system cannot find the file specified)

Even though I was able to mock the file and set the path to the file.

Any suggestion on how to mock the scanner class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution for this, I just created the file in the resource folder with the same file name and added dummy text to it. So that when the scanner statement gets executed in the test case it will read the dummy file.